# Representation of quiver $1 \to 2 \to 3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, representation-theory, quiver

Let $Q$ be a quiver $1 \to 2 \to 3$. How to determine whether the following two representations are isomorphic, in other words, how to find invertible matrices $Q_1$, $Q_2$, $Q_3$ such that the following diagram commutes:
\begin{matrix}
& K^n & \overset{A}{\longrightarrow} & K^m &\overset{B}{\longrightarrow} & K^r \\
& \downarrow_{Q_3} &  & \downarrow_{Q_2} & & \downarrow_{Q_1} \\
& K^n & \overset{I_A}{\longrightarrow} & K^m & \overset{I_B}{\longrightarrow} &   K^r
\end{matrix}
where $I_A$ is a diagonal matrix whose upper left $r(A)\times r(A)$ ($r(A)$ denotes the rank of a matrix $A$) block is the identity matrix and all other entries are zero, $n,m,r\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$.

For an example:
\begin{matrix}
& K^3 & \overset{A}{\longrightarrow} & K^2 &\overset{B}{\longrightarrow} & K \\
& \downarrow_{Q_3} &  & \downarrow_{Q_2} & & \downarrow_{Q_1} \\
& K^3 & \overset{I_A}{\longrightarrow} & K^2 & \overset{I_B}{\longrightarrow} &   K
\end{matrix}
Find $Q_1 \in K\backslash\{0\}$, an $2\times 2$ invertible matrix $Q_2$, an $3\times 3$ invertible matrix $Q_3$, such that 
\begin{align*}
Q_1 B =I_B Q_2, \quad Q_2 A = I_A Q_3. 
\end{align*}

My idea is as follows: there exist $Q_1 \in K\backslash\{0\}$ and an $2\times 2$ invertible matrix $Q_2$ such that $Q_1BQ^{-1}_2$ is [equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_equivalence) to $I_B$. So 
\begin{matrix}
& K^3 & \overset{A}{\longrightarrow} & K^2 &\overset{B}{\longrightarrow} & K \\
& \downarrow_{Q_3} &  & \downarrow_{Q_2} & & \downarrow_{Q_1} \\
& K^3 & \overset{Q_2 A Q^{-1}_3}{\longrightarrow} & K^2 & \overset{I_B}{\longrightarrow} &   K
\end{matrix}

I am stuck whether there exists an invertible matrix $Q_3$ such that 
\begin{align*}
Q_2 A Q^{-1}_3 = I_A. 
\end{align*}

Who can give me a hint？  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do explicit calculations for your example. Write down the matrices using unknowns. The fact that the diagram commutes yields some relations on these unknowns. Then demand that the matrices are invertible and check whether this is possible with the given constraints. But other than that I would say that the approach of Hugh Thomas is better.

Comment: @Mathematician42 Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make use of the classification of indecomposable representations of this quiver.  As you may well know, it has six indecomposable representations up to isomorphism, with dimension vectors 100, 010, 001, 110, 011, and 111.  (I can add more details if this is unfamiliar.)

The top representation splits up as min($r(A),r(B)$) copies of the representation with dimension vector 111, max($r(A),r(B)$)-min($r(A),r(B)$) copies of either 110 or 011 (depending on which of $r(A), r(B)$ is larger), and enough copies of each simple representation to get to the right dimension.

Then determine the number of copies of each of the indecomposable representations in the bottom representation.

Edited to add: in the example which you added, it isn't necessarily true that the two representations are isomorphic, but suppose they are.  The map $I_A$ has a one-dimensional kernel, so $A$ must as well.  An isomorphism would have to send the kernel of $A$ to the kernel of $I_A$.  That gives you a first step towards defining $Q_3$.  Next, I would consider the kernel of $I_B$.

Note that there is no reason to expect that the matrices $Q_i$ should be integer-valued -- they would normally be matrices over $K$.

Edited to add: It is certainly not true that the two representations will be isomorphic for an arbitrary choice of $A$ and $B$.

**The following example is wrong (as the OP kindly points out in comments)**:
For an extreme example, let $A$ and $B$ be the zero matrices (of the appropriate sizes).  Then that representation would be isomorphic to 3 copies of the simple representation at vertex 1, two copies of the simple at vertex 2, and one copy of the simple representation at vertex 3.  Since quiver representations satisfy Krull-Schmidt, so that a module has a unique expression as a sum of indecomposable modules, this rules out the possibility that it is isomorphic to the other representation you gave.  (Though it could also be instructive to prove directly that in this case, there are no matrices $Q_i$ which would give an isomorphism.)

**Here is one that works:** Consider the direct sum of the representations with dimension vectors 110 and 011.  The maps $A$ and $B$ are both rank 1, so $$I_A=[1\ 0],\  I_B=\left[ \begin{array}{c}1\\0\end{array} \right]$$

For $110\oplus 011$, the composition of the two maps is zero, while the for the representation defined by $I_A$ and $I_B$, the composition of the two maps is non-zero.  The property of the composition being zero or non-zero will be preserved by isomorphisms, so the representations are not isomorphic.

Comment: @ Hugh Thomas Thank you very much. I only know the result that it has six indecomposable representations. I don't know why?  Is there any conclusions about the number of indecomposable representions for a quiver?

Comment: The questions you are asking in your comment would probably be good as separate questions.  Any quiver obtained by taking an unoriented path of length n, and then providing an arbitrary orientation to each edge, has n+1 choose 2 indecomposable representations: each corresponds to a choice of substring, and is obtained by putting one copy of the ground field at each vertex in the substring, and identity maps between them.  (This is a special fact about the path-shaped quiver -- generally indecomposable representations can be more complicated.)

Comment: @ Hugh Thomas Thank you very much.

Comment: @Huge Thomas I think that the extreme example you give is as follows: \begin{matrix}
& K^3 & \overset{0}{\longrightarrow} & K^2 &\overset{0}{\longrightarrow} & K \\
& \downarrow_{I_3} &  & \downarrow_{I_2} & & \downarrow_{1} \\
& K^3 & \overset{0}{\longrightarrow} & K^2 & \overset{0}{\longrightarrow} &   K
\end{matrix} where $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

Comment: The maps in the bottom row of the diagram in your comment are zero, but in the diagram in the question, they are $I_A$ and $I_B$.  I'm afraid I'm not sure what point you are making.

Comment: Thank you. I mean that $I_A$ is a diagonal matrix whose upper left $r(A)\times r(A)$ block is the identity matrix and all other entries are zero, where $r(A)$ is the rank of a matrix $A$,  $n,m,r\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$. If $A = 0$, then $I_A = 0$.

Comment: @Huge Thomas Thank you very much for your answer.